# Plugin to Display Content on Page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am creating a plugin in which I will need to display content on a page. I have seen plugins that allow an administrator to put something like [display-content] in the visual editor which displays the plugin content to a website visitor. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).